# How to pass ggplot2 themes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an older ggplot2 book and it is outdated. It mentions using qplot, and opts.

I am trying to learn how to setup a ggplot2 graph correctly. I would like to know if my following code is the "correct" or "accepted" way of doing things.

I would like to pass themes to a plot, like title, axis titles, grid lines, colors of plot window, etc...

Currently this code block works until I attempt to pass a theme where I change the title. Here is the code, and a picture of the graph it makes before I pass the theme

```
brooks.sr <- ggplot(data=sim_dat, aes(x=rates, y=means))
brooks.sr.line <-  brooks.sr + geom_line(data=sim_dat[sim_dat$stream=="Brooks", ]) + 
geom_hline(aes(yintercept=.944), colour = "red")
```

[image]

then I try to add this line of code

```
brooks.sr.line + theme(title = element_text("Mean LWD Density across Sampling Rates"))
```

And i get this error

```
> brooks.sr.line + theme(title = element_text("Mean LWD Density across    Sampling Rates"))
Warning messages:
1: In grid.Call(L_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
  font family not found in Windows font database
2: In grid.Call(L_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
  font family not found in Windows font database
3: In grid.Call(L_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
  font family not found in Windows font database
4: In grid.Call.graphics(L_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
  font family not found in Windows font database
5: In grid.Call.graphics(L_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
  font family not found in Windows font database
```

I know have the following code block, which seems better, and I have added a title and line. But, I can not find out how to change the Axis titles, I can see where you can pass the theme and element to modify the text of the title, but not change the title itself

```
speelyai.sr <- ggplot(data=sim_dat, aes(x=rates, y=means))
speelyai.sr.line <-  speelyai.sr +   
geom_line(data=sim_dat[sim_dat$stream=="Speelyai", ]) + 
geom_hline(aes(yintercept=.584), colour = "red");speelyai.sr.line
speelyai.sr.line + ggtitle("Mean LWD Density using Simple Random 
 Sampling\nunder different Sampling Efforts") +
               theme(plot.title=element_text(size=rel(1.5), family="Times", face="bold"))
```

[image]
Thanks for any help

Comment: `theme` is used to control the *appearance*, while the *content* has to be set with other functions, e..g `ggtitle()` for the title text, `labs()` for the axis titles, etc.

Comment: Spot on. Thanks Baptiste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for titling the plot:

```
+ labs(title = expression("Mean LWD Density across Sampling Rates"))
```

You can also label the y and x-axes from the same line of code:

```
+ labs(x="X-Title", y="Y-Title", title = expression("Mean LWD Density across Sampling Rates"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Actually I found that ggtitle is for titling the plot, and labs is best to use for x and y axis labels! Thanks for leading me down the right path. Now if I cuold just find out why I keep getting all these errors that say Font Family Not Found In Windows Font Database

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `labs` to title the plot as well. Having a different function just for the title always seemed weird to me. I suppose there's also `xlab()` and `ylab()`, you just don't see people using them very often.